# Device having iOS 5.0.1 Not Detected in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

iOS device not detected having OS version 5.0.1 in XCode 4.2 installed on Mac OS 10.6.8
when we select connected device in organiser following Error occure

> Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC00D)
>
> Permission denied, at
>   ‘/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-867/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit_Utilities.m:944’

Comment: You really should accept some answers to previous questions you've asked.  It will encourage others to help you and that's how StackOverflow grows.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

Just quit iTunes, and disconnect - reconnect your device. Was having this issue, this manipulation solved it for me (on a Snow Leopard OSX).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after updating the AppStore version of Xcode 4.3 to 4.3.1. Only thing helped was deleting the /Applications/Xcode.app and reinstalling it from the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a stupid question but have you tried updating your XCode to 4.2.1? It is the one posted on November 17th. That might help.

Also, you could try removing the device from Organizer and re-adding it.

Lastly, try shutting down your device, then powering back on and reconnecting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had already tried it before posting this question.but it did not Work.but thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Shut down itunes as Kenji described.
Then click Add Device to Provisioning Portal in the Organizer.
Disconnect physically. It should work.