# Device is not detecting in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios6

I am new to iOS,

I built a code in Xcode 6.1 deployment Target, but it is not working in 6.1.3 simulator or with 6.1.3 device OS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 6.1 means it works in iOS 6.1 or later.

Comment: What you get in simulator or even cann't see anything in your simulator? Is it get launch or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be following reasons for your problem:

1. Your deployment target is greater than your device iOS version.
2. Provisioning profile is not configured properly for your device.
3. You don't have a developer certificate in XCode to work with the device.
4. You Device is not ready for development.

What you can do:
1. Just quit iTunes, and disconnect - reconnect your device.
2. you could try removing the device from Organizer and re-adding it.
3. Try clicking "Use for Development" on your device in the Xcode Organizer.
4. Stupid but try this also closing and re-opening xcode.

And for simulator problem, You might have to reset contents & settings for particular simulator. Worked for me...

Comment: possible copy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225728/ios-device-having-7-0-2-not-detected-in-xcode-5, kenji's answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575011/device-having-ios-5-0-1-not-detected-in-xcode-4-2

Comment: I think, my answer is incorrect, may be answer of other question. So I have deleted my answer. :)

Comment: Any how...Thanx for pointing out that I searched for better answers, instead of just giving vague answers. Thanx @Mani